# How to INSERT SELECT... WHERE NOT EXISTS SELECT?

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

I have a series of weblog entries in table exp_weblog_titles t.  That are categorized by categories in table exp_categories c and joined by table exp_category_posts cp.

There is a parent child relationship in categories. At this time I would like to take all my entries that are currently categorized with children of category 4810 and categorize those entries themselves with category 4810.

This is the (untested) query I have come up with for this operation:

```
INSERT INTO exp_category_posts (entry_id,cat_id)
(select distinct(t.entry_id), '4810' 
from
    exp_weblog_titles t
        left join
    exp_category_posts cp ON t.entry_id = cp.entry_id
        left join
    exp_categories c ON c.cat_id = cp.cat_id
where
    t.weblog_id = 5 and c.parent_id = 4810)
```

But I would like to avoid inserting new join records in category_posts cp where an identical one might exist.

I can't get my head around the WHERE NOT EXISTS.  Should it be part of the insert operation, the subselect?  Can't figure it either way.

It would be something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
SELECT * FROM exp_category_posts 
where cat_id = 4810 and entry_id = $thecurrentrow
```

But do I refer to the current row?

This is in ExpressionEngine 1.

**Update** arising from Mats's Answer: There is no unique key on (entry_id, cat_id).  Not sure of the  consequences of adding one.

Comment: Just a note. If there is no key, then a full table scan is needed on each insert, which is very expensive performance-wise. It is probably good to have an index on the table if you are going to do a lot of these inserts instead of doing the job in the application layer.

**Update:** How many rows are there in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `(entry_id, cat_id)` is a unique key in `exp_category_posts` you should be able to use `INSERT IGNORE`. The `INSERT IGNORE` will skip records that would generate a duplicate key error when being inserted.

You can find more information in the reference manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html.

Comment: Thanks Mats.  There is no such key currently and I am unsure of the consequences of creating it. It seems to me that the EE design philosophy is to put most of this sort of logic into the application layer.

Comment: You would add an index. It takes up space, potentially a lot if you have big tables. It prevents duplicate entries though, which seems like something you would like to do for this table anyway.